# 1С 8.2 - Веб-сервисы в 1С

Tags: 1с, веб-программирование, веб-служба

**Здравствуйте!**

Имеется самописная конфигурация 1С на управляемых формах. **Требуется сделать следующее:**

> необходим механизм синхронизации
> покупателей с сайтом, используя при
> этом веб сервисы (т.е. создали
> покупателя на сайте - покупатель попал
> в 1С, создали покупателя в 1С - он
> попал на сайт).

С веб-сервисами не работал еще. Нашел такой объект конфигурации. Опубликовал в IIS конфигурацию. **Подскажите пожалуйста, в каком ракурсе дальше копать?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для двустороннего обмена нужны веб-сервисы с двух сторон.

Веб-сервис 1С предназначен для доступа извне к базе 1С. Т.е. для случая "на сайте создали покупателя, сайт стукнулся к веб-сервису 1С, вызвал метод, покупатель добавился в 1С". Как работать с этим вебсервисом гуглить на тему "1с веб-сервис soap".

Для обратного действия аналогично необходимо реализовать веб-сервис на сайте. При этом это не обязательно должен быть SOAP, хотя в 1С и есть инструмент работы с WS-ссылками и целиком объект 1С в принципе кидать будет удобнее... В 1С можно дергать сайт по подписке на событие записи объекта в соответствующем справочнике, т.е. в потроха конфигурации лезть не нужно.

Вообще двусторонний обмен редко делают, если только в качестве дополнительного функционала. Лучше выбрать одно направление обмена (например сайт => 1С), тогда многих проблем можно будет избежать. А они будут скорее всего и так.

Comment: Недавно делал двухсторонний обмен, ничего сложного вроде. На сайте генератор определенного контента, на 1С регламентное задание, которое в определённое время стучится на сайт, забирает инфу и записывает её в 1С. И обратно: на события в 1С стоят подписки. При записи какого-нибудь документа идет запрос на сайт в определенными параметрами.

Comment: Под сайтом Вы подразумеваете своб опубликованную конфигурацию (пускай даже на локальной машине) или например полноценный сайт типа интернет-магазина?

Comment: @chudo116 полноценный сайт. Менеджерам стало удобней работать с товарами. Например, больше не нужно вручную вбивать на сайте цены (т.е. вбили в 1С и пошли гулять), при продаже на сайте (через платежку какую-нибудь) проданный товар также заносится автоматически. По сути автоматизировать можно всё, что угодно.

Comment: @lampa все верно. про двусторонний я имел ввиду что покупатели вбиваются и в 1с и на сайте. Неудобно когда база ведется в двух местах. С товарами еще хуже ситуация - номенклатуру приводить в порядок сложнее.
а когда обмен идет разными данными в разные стороны это нормально и удобно, да. на сайт товары, с сайта заказы и покупатели - самый простой и удобный вариант.

Comment: Интересует вопрос - на данный моменту меня нету сайта, с которым можно настроить обмен из 1С. Существует ли возможность проверить    работу веб-сервиса без него? Може эмуляторы штоль какие есть)

Comment: [Веб-сервисы в 1С](http://fix-in.narod.ru/articles/1s_web_services/article.htm) - Тестирование веб-сервиса 1С.

Answer (score -2):

ставите веб-сервер на локальную машину и тестите :)